# What does R do with negative values in log() scale?

Tags: r, data-transformation, optimal-scaling

**Some context of the problem:**

I am working on an analysis of some hypothetical donation data: I would like to investigate the differences between 'major donors' (those whose largest single donation is over \$10K) and 'regular donors' (those whose largest single donation is less than \$10K).

Specifically, I am looking at whether there is a difference in the percentage change  (positive or negative) from a donor's first gift to their next. (I am excluding donors who have given \$10K or over on their first donation)

Naturally, I have a large right skew of values ranging from negative values (i.e. -0.70 to 5.00). I would like to visualize the data in an informative way - so **what is the best transformation/scale I should use?**

I have tried plotting on a histogram of frequencies of `log(percentageChange)` :

[image]

What does R do with the negative values?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Given that $\log(1) = 0$, any value $0 < x < 1$ will yield negative values in $\log(x)$.

Comment: Ahh yes of course. Sorry brain slip. Does R just omit negative values in the plot (as in the negative percent changes?)

Comment: It computes their value as `NaN`, but `hist()` only uses the finite values in the data set plotted (via `is.finite()`) and `is.finite(NaN)` returns `FALSE`). In other words `hist()` just ignores those values when plotting; as most(all?) other plotting functions in R would (or should!).

Comment: I'd guess that many people give donations of rounded amounts, and if they change, the changes are also rounded. So, histograms will show much noise from money amount preferences and their side-effects. As the data are stated to be hypothetical, they presumably have the structure their makers imparted, but these could be key details for real data.

Comment: The biggest spikes here are at 0 and -2 (if I read the graph correctly). So log % change is frequently 0 and so % change is frequently 1; and the most common log % change is -2 (are you using log base 10 or natural logarithms). These seem bizarre features. Is your variable really what its name implies?

Answer (score 4):

Well, you might consider editing your question to either ask which transformation to use or what's going on with that plot, but as to the latter, the log function *outputs* negative values for input between 0 and 1. It's only for non-positive *inputs* that log is undefined.

So there's nothing particularly alarming about that graph, but it's unclear from your question what it is actually displaying. Is it actually percentage change (which as you said, contains negative values)?

You might also consider splitting the data in ways that make sense, like only looking at donors whose donations decrease, in which case you could flip the sign and log to your heart's content.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. Yes, had a major brain lapse - regarding the negative values.